# AWS what cloudwatch metrics use to monitor an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, distributed-system

I have an application for data storage with servers that are distributed on multiple EC2 instances (data are extra small file that are stored in an in memory derby DB).

For needs of scalability I have to create/destroy a new server in order to manage the increase of user and data.

What metrics I should use to watch?

In general I think I have to see `CPUUtilization`.

For user increase maybe I should control network utilization? But which metrics of network?

While for data increase I have to watch to what kind of memory usage metrics?

Comment: If you tried to run everything on one server, what problem occurs first? Does it run out of memory? Does it slow down due to CPU requirements? The only way to really know what to watch is to simulate user workloads, monitor all metrics and then figure out what causes the first bottleneck. Every application is different!

Comment: Firs of all thanks for your help.
Yes of course, my question was generic.
I mean if a lot of users try to connect to my server does it is possible that it should have problems due to network saturation? if yes what metrics i should watch networkIN , networkOUT,other?
CloudWatch metrics are lots i only needs simple ones .
Furthermore it could be possible for my application to use a lot of CPU and not much Memory when a lot of user try store very small data,and it also could be possible that few users try to store a bigger data and then saturates memory while not using lots of CPU.

Comment: Every application is different, so it is not possible to provide general advice. It depends whether the application is doing CPU-intensive operations, transferring a lot of data, accessing a database, querying external information, etc. For example, the whole of StackOverflow [can run on a single web server](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/) (plus database, search system, etc). So, it really depends on what your application is doing.